# Selenium ActionChains simulated mouse control with Python is 10x slower than simulated keystrokes - why is this, and is there a better way?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm building a Selenium ActionChain via Python to hold and execute keyboard and mouse input. When the ActionChain only contains several keystrokes (through `action.key_down()` or `action.key_up()`), it executes in well under 0.01 s. As soon as I add a single cursor movement (using `action.move_by_offset()`) the execution time shoots up to 0.3-0.4 s.

First off, what's the technical difference that makes the mouse input so much more expensive?

Is there any better Selenium-based alternative, or should I be using a different tool for realtime browser input?

(For context, I'm using Selenium to run a reinforcement learning model on HTML5 multiplayer web games, so I need to execute actions as quickly as possible or my bot's reaction time suffers. I'm using the Firefox webdriver - I also tried Chrome, but found the geckodriver to be about twice as fast for mouse input. Ideally, I need to get all of my input execution to run in about 0.01 s so it doesn't slow down my model.)

Comment: FWIW: `key_up()` and `move_by_offset()` are in [common/action_chains.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py).  The first method points to [common/actions/key_actions.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/key_actions.py); the second to [/common/actions/pointer_actions.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/pointer_actions.py).  But I don't know enough about the implementation details to answer why one is more performant.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking for a fix here is what I did:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver, duration=10)  # duration in milliseconds
actions.move_to_element_with_offset(website_element, x, y).perform()
```

I found this out from looking a bit in the source and seeing a duration argument that was left on the default of 250 ms. Does anyone know why they do this?

I dont know the answers to your other questions though

Answer (score 0):

I still can't answer why the issue exists beyond orde's note above, but I did find that Selenium doesn't seem like the best tool for this, and was able to (somewhat crudely) work around it using additional libraries.

For anyone else with a similar need:
I ended up using [D3DShot](https://pypi.org/project/D3DShot/) for video (much faster frame grab than Selenium) and [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for much faster mouse control (closer to 1 ms). I still utilize Selenium, but only to navigate to the site, log in, and put the game window in full screen.

Unfortunately this setup effectively prevents multiple bots from running on the same machine (you might be able to hack something together with one bot per display, but that would get pretty messy.)